# How can i access a virtual method of a class with her adress/without using the name of the method

Tags: c++, function-pointers, virtual-functions

```
class Base{
public:
  virtual int first()=0;
  virtual int second()=0;
};

class Derived: public Base{
public:
  virtual int first(){return 5;}
  virtual int second(){return 15;}
};
```

This is my code, and i'm trying for practice to access it using only pointers and addresses but i can't wrap my head around the specifics of function pointers in this case, i tried a lot of different options and got a lot of different errors.

Additional explenation as requested:

Lets say my class Derived is on address 40000. With my, still new, understanding the function should be written on address 40001 or similar. Does c++ give ability to just invoke a method on address 40001, or any other solution where i completely avoid the name of the method.

Comment: What method do you want to call?

Comment: I would like to print both "5" and "15".

Comment: "the function should be written on address 40001 or similar" No, this is absolutely not the case.

Comment: You absolutely can't reliably predict which address the function will use.

Comment: @bennji_of_the_overflow Are you sure? Im still transitioning from C, so i believe you. But in C, the functions would be just on an offset from a structure (as it is inside it). Also. when i print (what i tought will be) the address of the method like this:

    printf("%d", &Derived::first)

it prints "1". I read somewhere else that it works like an offset. If you could clarify that  for me that would be great.

Comment: @Branko Try `printf("%p %p",&Derived::first,&Derived::second);`

Answer (score 1):

You can declare function pointer to member functions.Something like

```
   int (Derived::*firstptr)();
   firstptr = &Derived::first;
   int (Derived::*secondptr)();
   secondptr = &Derived::second;
```

and then

```
   Derived obj;  
   std::cout << (obj.*firstptr)()<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<(obj.*secondptr)()<<std::endl;
```

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but i was hoping to find another way. Lets say my class Derived is on address 40000. With my, still new, understanding the function should be written on address 40001 or similar. Does c++ give ability to just invoke a method on address 40001, or any other solution where i completely avoid the name of the method.

Comment: Not that i am aware of.Please put this thing in your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Branko You have to use the names of the method to get a pointer.  Once you have a pointer you can use the pointer's name instead of the method name. There is no other way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the method with a pointer (with the name):

```
Derived d = new Derived();
Derived* pDerived = &d;
cout << pDerived->first();
cout << pDerived->second();
```

but, in my knowledge, there is no way to access a function with only a memory address.